# Is there a load event for HTML Body element? I can't seem to get it to work - show an alert

Tags: html

I am trying to attach a listener for the HTML body's load event. But the code doesn't seem to run (event not fired). Is there a load event for the body element? If yes, is the code below correct? Right now I just want it to work in Firefox.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.addEventListener('load', function() {
      alert("Body has loaded");
    }, true);
}
```

I know I can do it with jQuery's $(document).ready(); But I want to learn the native DOM methods. Also, I don't want to use `<body onload="">`. I want to attach the event the way I have shown, at runtime.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `load` event on `<body>`, but it will already have fired by the time you add the listener in `window.onload`.

Using `window.onload` itself is fine: when that fires, you know the entire page has already loaded. The idea of `$(document).ready()` is that *sometimes* it can fire earlier than `window.onload`, which waits for all the page's resources (eg images) to load before firing.

How to detect the body content being loaded *before* `window.onload` fires is quite a complex story, which is why frameworks like jQuery hide it all under their own event. On modern browsers you can do it by listening for the `DOMContentLoaded` event. On some browsers such as IE there are some ugly browser-specific hacks to guess that the body content is loaded; on older browsers you have no choice but to fall back to `window.onload`.

To avoid having to implement this sort of complex code you can try just putting a hook call in at the end of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(initialiseThings, 0);
</script></body></html>
```

(The `setTimeout` being there to allow the browser to pick up the `</body>` tag, finishing loading the body element and avoiding problems in IE if you try to `appendChild` onto `<body>` in your initialisation code before the body is closed. You can omit the timeout if you're not doing anything like that.)

Answer (score 0):

IFAIK is the `<body onload="">` the same event as `window.onload` so your second function is "to late". BTW: the jQery function is way smarter: The browser calls `window.onload` if every resource is loaded completely. The jQuery function is called when the document (the `html`) is loaded.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. so, window.onload is fired when the document's body completes loading?