# javascript loads in browser but nothing executes

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log('hi')}
)
```

```css
h1, h2{
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
}
body{
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    overflow-x :hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1 style="font-size: 50px;" id = "hi">Hi</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

(By the way, this isn't the full code. It is just some placeholder stuff.)

As you can see from the snippet, the 'hi' doesn't appear in the console.log. Any ideas why?

Comment: DOMContentLoaded

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log('hi')}
)
?

Comment: 'load' is a `window` event. Use `window.addEventListener('load', () => {})`

Comment: Could use `document.body.addEventListener` instead for the `load` event target.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl — [Nonsense](https://jsbin.com/pijoquheda/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: @Quentin my bad. It does have one, but it will [fire before `window.onload`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4400692/1762224). Good catch.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl — Bob is wrong. There's no load event on the body. There is an `onload` *attribute* which maps to the window's load event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Answer (score 5):

There is no `load` event fired on the `document` object.

You could use [a `DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) or listen for [a load event on the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event).

Note that they fire at different times, so make sure you read the documentation to understand which is right for you.

---

You might also wish to remove the event listener entirely and use a [`defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) to delay script execution instead.

This would delay script execution until after the DOM was ready (which is *probably* why you are trying to use an event handler here) while also allowing the script to download in parallel with the HTML being parsed (which is a slight performance enhancement).

Comment: Okay, I have another problem now, the js isn't listening to a document.addEventListener('scroll,', function(){}. Any ideas why?

Comment: @jkimishere — If you have a new question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (and include a [mcve]).

Answer (score 3):

You are listening to the wrong event.
E.g.

```js
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event